# Can't deploy webpack project to Netlify

Tags: webpack, eslint, webpack-dev-server, netlify, eslintrc

I've just built my first project with a webpack and am trying to deploy it to Netlify, but to no avail. I have no issues if I build, start, or lint on my own machine, but Netlify gets hung up on my eslint.  The funny thing is that I have the exact environment as other students in my class and they were able to deploy with no issues.

The error in Netlify's log:

```
1:47:21 PM: WARNING in ./src/main.js
1:47:21 PM: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):
1:47:21 PM: No ESLint configuration found in /opt/build/repo/src.
1:47:21 PM: ERROR in ./src/main.js
1:47:21 PM: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):
```

My webpack configurations:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /spec/],
        loader: "eslint-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The relevant bits of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "node-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "start": "npm run build; webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "lint": "eslint src/*.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.6.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  }
```

And my source code:
https://github.com/kwicz/galactic-age-calculator

I've tried updating my webpack rules, changing to production mode, etc. etc. but am not making much progress here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> 1:47:21 PM: No ESLint configuration found in /opt/build/repo/src.

The above error line points to a missing `.eslintrc` config file missing in your repository. You may not have committed it into your repository code and pushed it to GitHub.

If you clone your repository into a clean directory onto your machine and run the build command exactly like Netlify would, you should see the same error.

**Note:** Your repository also does not have a `.gitignore` file which should also be included with the following. This is not affecting anything, but might help you avoid pushing development and production files into your repository.

```
node_modules/
dist/
```

Comment: Thank you! I do indeed have a .gitignore with those files in it, as well as a .eslintrc and .babelrc.  However, I didn't notice that git add * didn't throw them into the repo and I never manually added them.  The second I did, my site was up and running.  I really appreciate it.